# fixing flat tire

Tags: puncture

I had to repair a flat. 
Have some questions.

Is it best to apply patch to a completly flat tube?

I found a small copper wire in tire.

Is there something to minimize what can puncture tire?

Thanks

Comment: There are many video tutorials and guides for puncture repair on the internet you can us Google to find. Most bike tire manufacturers make puncture resistant tires.

Comment: Be sure to remove that piece of copper wire from the tyre or it'll just puncture your repair.

Comment: A) You should get most of the air out of the tube.  Generally you remove the valve core to do this.  B) If there's something like a piece of wire stuck in the tire, definitely remove it.  When you patch a tube, *always* check the inside of the tire (feel with your hand), looking for anything sticking through.  I'd say about one time in four you find something.  C) There are puncture-resistant tires and tire liners -- quite a variety, in fact.

Comment: I read conflicting reviews on tires and liners. Any recommendations? You can use answers like Cont*#ental etc. :-)

Comment: @fixit7 comments are not for chat - consider the [chat] instead.